# UISearchDisplayController usage with network-fetched data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` subclass that renders a list of pre-set categories and fetches a list of sites/urls for each of them. I want to add a search capability that would allow to search by a site name.

What I want is to have a usual search interface, that would start a search thread (that would fetch and process results) and then show it in the table. I've modified my table delegate to return custom set of cells if the `UITableView` is not the one form xib (i.e. it's a search table view):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RSSCatalogCell";

    if(tableView != self.tableView)
        return [searchController tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // ... usual cell initialization for categories
}
```

As soon as my network thread (spawned from `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:`) finishes, it asks a search controller table to reload the data:

```
if(searchDisplayController.active)
    [searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

But I still see the old table (with catalog entires), however it seem to ignore touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it (I hate that when you clearly write a question to some public group/forum you might quickly find your own bug after spending several days looking for it).

The problem was in one wrong connection in XIB, the above code is working perfectly.